# I just downloaded webkitGTK using svn and I am not sure what to do next

Tags: gtk, webkit

here https://live.gnome.org/WebKitGtk/ it says to

Run the following commands to configure and build WebKit (choosing an appropriate prefix):

```
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr
make
```

but I am not sure what they mean by 'appropriate prefix'. Can anyone offer a clue?

Answer (score 2):

Prefix is a directory under which the compiled application is going to be installed. I'd use something like `/opt/WebKitGtk` to be sure it does not override anything. Installing in `/usr` is definitely not a good idea.

Also note I corrected a typo in your command example - `make` should be a separate command.

Good luck :)

Comment: wait. One more thing: Why did you choose opt? I was thinking of putting it in home/magpie. would that work for my various ends?

Comment: Yes, your home dir is fine too, if you're the only user on that system who will be using it. This is even better as it won't require superadmin privileges to install